# How do I change the add to cart text for specific variations in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

In my WooCommerce store I have simple products and variable products, both simple products and variations have a meta value of 'pre_order' which is yes/no.

If this option is set on the backend I want to have the add to cart button say 'Pre-Order' as opposed to 'Add To Cart'.

For simple products I have had no issue changing this using filters or editing file templates, variations seem much trickier though...

When variation options are selected then the price and sku updates, during this process I also want to check the meta value mentioned above and if that variation has the meta value pre order of 'yes' then I would also like to change the button text but I cannot find a way to do so!

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce provide a hidden input field named variation_id. As soon as variation changes, updated variation id is saved in this hidden input field. So first you have to detect using jQuery when the value of this input field is updated, when detected fire your own ajax request and check whether this variation was assigned for pre order or not if yes now you can change the text of add to cart after the response of ajax is success.

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce stores the variation details (like price, dimensions, weight etc) in a data attribute named `data-product_variations` in `.variations_form` element. This data is used to show the price and other details when user selects a particular variation. You can add your meta value in this data attribute using a filter `woocommerce_available_variation` something like:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'vna_add_variation_meta');
function vna_add_variation_meta($dataattr, $product, $variation) {
    $dataattr['pre_order'] = get_post_meta($variation->get_id(), 'pre_order', true);
    return $dataattr;
}
```

You can find more details about `woocommerce_available_variation` in `class-wc-product-variable.php` file.

Once you have got the meta value in DOM element, you can use following event to know when user has selected a variation.

```
$( ".single_variation_wrap" ).on( "show_variation", function ( event, variation ) {
    // Fired when the user selects all the required dropdowns / attributes
    // and a final variation is selected / shown
    // Here you will need to get the value of 'pre_order' from the variation object
    // something like: variation.pre_order
    // and take appropriate action
} );
```

Please note: code is untested so there could be some typos ;)